# how can i flip a card in a material2 angular2 list of cards

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, angular-material

I am trying to create a list of cards in which I can flip each one separately using material2 and angular. The problem is when I try to flip one card all the cards in the list is flipped. I have tried different versions of the code below with the same results...

**flip-card-component.html**

```
<div class="tp-wrapper">


  <md-list-item class="tp-list" *ngFor="let  upcomingEvent of upcomingEvents">
   <!-- <md-card [ngClass]="'event-item'">  -->   

    <div class="tp-box" (click)="toggleFlip()" [@flipState]="flip">
    <!-- <md-card> -->
      <div class="tp-box__side tp-box__front"> 
     <!--  <md-card [ngClass]="'event-item'"> -->
        <h4 [ngClass]="'event-title'" [ngStyle]="{'color':'purple'}"> {{upcomingEvent.title}}</h4>
     <!--  </md-card> -->
      </div> 
      <div class="tp-box__side tp-box__back">Back
      </div>
      <!-- </md-card> -->
     </div>

   <!--  </md-card>  -->

  </md-list-item>


 </div>
```

**flip-card-component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UpcomingEvent } from './../../interface/upcomingevent';

import { trigger,state,style,transition,animate,keyframes } from '@angular/animations';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-flip-card',
  templateUrl: './flip-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flip-card.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('flipState', [
      state('active', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(179.9deg)'
      })),
      state('inactive', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(0)'
      })),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('500ms ease-out')),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('500ms ease-in'))
    ])  
  ]
})
export class FlipCardComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input()
    upcomingEvents: Array<UpcomingEvent>;
   @Input()
     selectedEvent: UpcomingEvent;

    flip: string = 'inactive';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleFlip() {
    this.flip = (this.flip == 'inactive') ? 'active' : 'inactive';
  }
}
```

can this be done? In other words I want my list to show multiple vertical scrolling cards in which when I clink on one it flips....any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @moshe No never did.....I put the experiment on hold for now will get back to it in a week or so.  The main problem was trying to do this with a vertical list of cards where the cards are in effect a vertical carousel with continuous scroll

Comment: If you can get it done for one, I can get it to work in a vertical scroll for you

Comment: Ok....I can get it to flip...so I will make contact in a week or so when I get back to it.